# UART communication dsPIC33EP256MU810

Tags: communication, microcontroller, uart, baud-rate, dspic

I'm very much new to Microcontroller programming.

I'm using

- MplabX v3.26  as IDE
- XC16 compiler
- PICKit 3
- p33EP256MU810 (dspic)

for programing

I have written very simple program to blink LED and send few characters over UART, please refer to following source code:

```c
#include <p33Exxxx.h>
#include <p33EP256MU810.h>
#include <libpic30.h>
#include <uart.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pps.h>
#include <xc.h>
#include <stdint.h>

// Configuration settings
_FOSC(FNOSC_FRCPLL);
_FWDT(FWDTEN_OFF);

int main() 
{    
//make all pins digital  
PADCFG1 = 0xFFFF; 

//set direction
TRISCbits.TRISC2 = 0;

//Initialze UART1
iPPSOutput(OUT_PIN_PPS_RP68, OUT_FN_PPS_U1TX);

//close UART
CloseUART1();

//open UART
OpenUART1(  UART_EN & UART_IDLE_CON & UART_DIS_WAKE & UART_DIS_LOOPBACK & UART_DIS_ABAUD & UART_NO_PAR_8BIT & UART_1STOPBIT,
            UART_TX_ENABLE & UART_INT_TX & UART_ADR_DETECT_DIS, 
            15);

while (1) 
{
    //turn on led 
    LATCbits.LATC2 = 1;
    __delay32(3750000);    // ~1 sec delay
    //turn off led
    LATCbits.LATC2 = 0;
    __delay32(3750000);    // ~1 sec delay


    //Transmit data
    while(BusyUART1());     //Wail till available
    WriteUART1(0x55);
    WriteUART1(0xaa);
    while(BusyUART1());     //Wail till all bytes sent
}

return 0;
}
```

LED blinking part works perfectly, but I'M receiving garbage characters on other end of UART where I'm using serial monitor tool (X-CTU) to monitor data.

My major issue is that I'm not able to calculate baudrate. Please let me know if I'm doing anything wrong.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

1. Clear ANSELx register to set pins digital, instead of writing to PADCFG1
2. Play with baud rate. Last parameter in procedure OpenUART1 specifies U1BRG value according to [dsPic tool description](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/51456b.pdf) page 147.
   You can also setup baud rate manually adding `U1BRG = value;` right after executing OpenUART1. 
   What value pass to UxBRG depends on clock speed and desired baud rate, more details in [manual for USART](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/70582D.pdf) page 9. Notice, that if setup baud rate manually need also set or clear `U1MODE.BRGH` bit.

Answer (score 1):

"My major issue is that I'm not able to calculate baudrate. Please let me know if I'm doing anything wrong."

I don't know what is desired baudrate but:

1. While making UxBRG calculation, please, take care to clock (oscillator) setup (since you are using `_FOSCSEL(FNOSC_FRCPLL)` with enabled PLL).
2. Issue that you've described sounds like a wrong baudrate (including oscillator) calculation, or it could be that port setup is wrong (databits, parity, stopbits).

Hope this helps...